# Куча и ее множественные трактовки

Tags: javascript, c++, алгоритм

Хочу познать суть) в общем есть куча. В си это динамическая область памяти, где аллоцируются объекты через new (говорю о ++). В js это место где выделяется память под переменые типа Объект.

Так вот. Один уважаемый лектор сказал что в js объекты хранятся в куче и это такая специальная структура данных посредством которой реализована память. Я думаю, этого не может быть, потому что для кучи нужно как минимум организовать операцию сравнения на всем пространстве одинаковых типов. Я быстро лезу в Википедию и получаю ответ что куча это структура данных посредством которой реализована динамическая область памяти.

Т.е. налицо отождествление понятий как куча динамическая память и куча как классическая структура данных. Где я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Нигде, куча - это и динамическая память и способ организации данных. Причем в С++ оно и в том, и в другом смысле используется. Есть алгоритмы - `make_heap`

Comment: Т.е. Вики ошибается?

Comment: Вики тоже не ошибается... [см разделъ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Куча)

Comment: В чем вики ошибается? Судя с ваших слов и уважаемый лектор с ней солидарен.

Comment: Вот потому в *нормальных* переводах четко различают heap и переводят как "куча" (хотя и тут корежит, если честно...) для области памяти, и как **пирамида** для структуры данных (мы же не говорим "сортировка кучей" - а **пирамидальная сортировка**). Преподу следует мягко указать на книги Кнута, Кормена и иже с ними, - там везде структура данных **пирамида**.

Comment: Какая-то терминологическая каша. Есть коса, которой траву косят, есть коса, которую из волос заплетают, и есть коса, которая в море выдается. Однако это не создает никакого "отождествления понятий". Так же и с кучей.

Answer (score 1):

Я не вижу тут отождествления, хотя формулировки мне кажутся корявыми.

В информатике у слова "куча", судя по Википедии, два значения:

Первое значение - [структура данных куча](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0_(%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)).

> В компьютерных науках ку́ча — это специализированная структура данных типа дерево, которая удовлетворяет свойству кучи ... <sub>бла<sub>бла<sub>бла</sub></sub></sub>

Т.е. значение 1 - вполне конкретная структура данных.

Второе значение - [куча как хранилище памяти](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0_(%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C)).

> Ку́ча (англ. heap) в информатике и программировании — название структуры данных, с помощью которой реализована динамически распределяемая память приложения.

Хотя тут и написано "название структуры данных", я так понимаю, речь идет не о первом значении слова куча (не о конкретной структуре данных), а вообще о любой структуре данных, через которую сделано динамическое выделение памяти в той или иной программе.

Т.е. значение 2 - любая структура данных, через которую организовано динамическое выделение памяти.